# How to make the textField first character to start with alphabet only?

Tags: javascript

How to make the textField first character to be alphabet only?

Comment: Do you mean, how to enforce validation on a input field so that the first character always has to be a letter?

Comment: you can use validation on the `keydown` for example and allow only alphabet character if text field empty, otherwise allow enything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use regular expressions to check it contents in `keydown` event. If it start from non letter character then clear the textbox. You can use regular expressions to check what's the first character.

For example:

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="javascript:checkContents(this)" />

<script type="text/javascript">
   var checkContents = function(input) {
      var text = input.value;
      if(!/[a-zA-Z]/.test(text))
         input.value = ""; 
   }
</script>
```